# Can't set background under Layout components React and Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to set the background image under my components. But it always is on top, so my elements are under it.
Or in the second variant, all works fine, except that I can't apply `blur-xl` only to the background. it applies to background and Layout elements.

> bg-repeat-y needs me to copy down my image, am I right?

```
import moons from './../assets/moon.svg'

const Background = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <div className='bg-white '>
            
            <div className='min-h-screen min-w-screen bg-repeat-y' style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${moons})` }}>
                <div className="div"></div>
        </div>
            {children}
        </div>
    );
}
export default Background;
```

This Background element wraps other elements in Laoyout in react-router-dom

```
export const AppLayout = () => (
    <div>
        <Background>
                <NewNavbar />
                <Outlet />
                <Footer />
        </Background>
    </div>
);
```

Help me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, the blur will be applied between your components & background image

```
export const AppLayout = () => (

<Background>
  <div class="backdrop-blur-xl h-full">
    <NewNavbar />
    <Outlet />
    <footer />
  </div>
</Background>
);
```

if you have any queries, refer to this link
https://play.tailwindcss.com/yX9aAMagRj

Answer (score 0):

For the first variant/approach that you mentioned, you can set the `z-index` of the background to negative using the class `-z-10` . Then your background will not come over your other elements.